# -ms-viewport causing div not scrolling

Tags: html, css, cordova, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

I seem to have encountered a very strange bug; I am doing an app for Windows Phone 8 with PhoneGap. The problem I am having is that that I have scrollable `div` which works when I use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, height=480, width=320, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

(I tried using `height=device-height`, `width=device-width`, all worked)

However, when I remove the viewport meta tag and use this instead:

```
@-ms-viewport {
    width:320px;
    user-zoom: fixed;
    max-zoom: 1;
    min-zoom: 1;
}
```

Everything looks the same **but** the `div` is not scrollable anymore.

I need to use `-ms-viewport` because I'll be putting it in media query because I want to change viewport width/height for portrait and landscape.

I tried removing/reinjecting the meta tag, changing meta tag's `content` values with jQuery, but it doesn't update the viewport at runtime.

Here is the HTML for the whole page. You should use on IE10 mobile if you wish to reproduce the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-190.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            @-ms-viewport {
                width: 320px;
                user-zoom: fixed;
                max-zoom: 1;
                min-zoom: 1;
            }

            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
                user-select: none;
            }

            body {
                background-color: red;
                color: white;
                -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
            }

            .window_wrapper {
                position: relative;
                background-color: yellow;
                width: 90%;
                height: 90%;
                overflow: auto;
            }

            .test {
                width: 50%;
                height: 500px;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: silver;
                z-index: 3000;
            }

            #ll {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0px;
            }
        </style>
        <title>An App...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="window_wrapper">
            <div class="test">
                first line
                <br />
                <div id="ll"> last line </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

### For Windows Phone 8

I faced the same issue and I was breaking my head until I used the following CSS:

```css
body {
    @-ms-viewport {
        width: 320px;
        user-zoom: fixed;
        max-zoom: 1;
        min-zoom: 1;
    }
}

div .scrollable-area {
    overflow: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

It worked; now I am able to scroll the area with no problem.

---

### For Windows Phone 8.1 +

As pointed by this [link](http://www.hippopunk.com/en/how-to-stop-the-bouncing-wp8-webview/) which is a working solution

```
html {  
    overflow: hidden;  
    -ms-content-zooming: none;  
}

body {  
   -ms-touch-action: pan-y ;  
}

div .scrollable-area {  
  overflow: auto ;  
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y ;  
}
```

**Credits to :**

Tweet@[r_desimone](https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=r_desimone)

Comment: Setting only `overflow:scroll;` and `-ms-overflow-style: none;` did the trick for me. Tested on Windows Phone 8 / IE10. Thank you very much - it is a miracle, indeed :o)

Comment: I was cracking my head almost a month... and found out the above solution. B ut be careful when u use input field. Initial versions on Win8 has bug. When you fix the viewport and click on input field. The screen shrinks when key board pops up. This is fixed in subsequent versions

Answer (score 1):

The `@ms-viewport` rule according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't support the setting of properties other than `width` or `height`.

So you may have to use a combination of the `meta` tag and the `@ms-viewport` rule, but just override the `width` and `height` each time using media queries for the different layouts

Answer (score 0):

```
body, html { 
  -ms-overflow-style: none !important; 
}
```