# Prevent bouncing effect in windows phone 8 app

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am developing multipage dynamic WP8 app. I need to disable WebBrowser default bouncing effect(like rubber band). I put the below line in my config file, it works fine in pages that didint have overflow scroll. If the contents loading dynamically and it has vertical scroll the bounce effect will appear. how can I solve this, pls help..

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Using cordova 3.4.0

Comment: what kind of bouncing effect are you talking about.?

Comment: What are you talking about at all? your question is very unclear..

Comment: I have edited the above question.actually there were some missing.now please go through this

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CordovaView.DisableBouncyScrolling = true; // add this line
        //Splash_Screen();
    }
```

this will solve your problem check this answer [Webview bounce in windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821436/webview-bounce-in-windows-phone-8)

Comment: I tried this, it stopped the bouncing, but now the overflow scroll is really rough, and sometimes not working.

Comment: This makes scrolling sluggish  yes. that the limitation

Comment: Guys is there any solution in phonegap 3.5 version?