# Cordova WP8 app - prevent dragging the viewport

Tags: cordova, viewport, drag

I'm making a cordova app and met something very annoying. When I start to drag some element of it - the whole viewport moves as well.

I made a pure Cordova app and it still has the same problem.

[image]

It doesn't happen on Cordova android app.

I tried some solutions for the "bouncing scrolling" problem - from the CSS, the meta tag in the HTML, from tags in config.xml or changex in some XAML files, none of them helped.

Any idea how to fix this? Cause I want it to be exactly as native apps, where such "dragging" of the whole "app" is just not happening.

Comment: Have you found the solution to this problem? I also have it and it makes the app look bad.

Comment: Yes, and I have forgotten to post the solution. Just posted it though, and hope at least one of the variants I've mentioned helps you :)

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research and finding the following variants, among others:

http://www.mattbarryonline.co.uk/tutorials/phonegap-disable-bounce-on-windows-phone/
http://www.hippopunk.com/en/how-to-stop-the-bouncing-wp8-webview/

I see now I've decided to go with this one:

[Prevent bouncing effect in windows phone 8 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652027/prevent-bouncing-effect-in-windows-phone-8-app)

So, now, I just have:

```
<preference name="disallowoverscroll" value="true"/>
```

right before the closing tag

```
</widget>
```

in my "config.xml" file.